# Create CTE or table variable with dynamic columns and data

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I would like to take the results of this pivoted query, and join them to results from another query at query run time.

Is there a way to declare a table variable with dynamic columns, then insert the query results into it so it can be joined with other tables? The first 4 columns would probably be static, but everything else in the query results could vary due to the number of rows returned.

Due to my permission level in the SQL Server, I do not have the capability to use temdb.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + QUOTENAME(item.dv_item_option_new)
                      FROM DATABASE.dbo.sc_req_item req
                        INNER JOIN sc_item_option_mtom AS mtom ON mtom.request_item = req.sys_id
                        INNER JOIN sc_item_option AS item ON item.sys_id = mtom.sc_item_option
                        INNER JOIN item_option_new AS itemdef ON itemdef.sys_id = item.item_option_new
                      WHERE req.task_effective_number = 'RITM****'
                        AND item.dv_item_option_new IS NOT NULL
                        AND item.value IS NOT NULL
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

SET @query = 'SELECT dv_stage, dv_state, dv_cat_item, task_effective_number, ' + @cols + '
             FROM 
             (
                SELECT req.dv_stage, req.dv_state, req.dv_cat_item, req.task_effective_number, item.value, item.dv_item_option_new
                FROM DATABASE.dbo.sc_req_item req
                  INNER JOIN sc_item_option_mtom AS mtom ON mtom.request_item = req.sys_id
                  INNER JOIN sc_item_option AS item ON item.sys_id = mtom.sc_item_option
                  INNER JOIN item_option_new AS itemdef ON itemdef.sys_id = item.item_option_new
                WHERE req.task_effective_number = ''RITM****''
                  AND item.dv_item_option_new IS NOT NULL
                  AND item.value IS NOT NULL
             ) p
             PIVOT
             (
                MAX(value)
                FOR dv_item_option_new IN (' + @cols + ')
             ) AS pvt'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: In short; no. You'll need to do *everything* in the dynamic statement.

Comment: Thank you. I will see if I can get someone in the DB side who can create a couple of Views that I could join together instead into a single query.

Comment: In truth, though, in you need to dynamically pivot your data you might want to consider if you should be pivoting your data in your SQL layer at all. Perhaps this is something you should be doing in your presentation layer.

Comment: `VIEW`s can't have dynamic definitions, so that isn't likely to give you the result you want.

Comment: i'm pretty sure every user has access to tempdb?

Comment: @siggemannen It is perfectly possible to revoke access to tempdb for users. However I don't see the reasoning behind doing so.

Comment: i wonder how that works, since queries sometimes use tempdb for spools etc. Perhaps it's possible without the rights